# Android Location Criteria what is Bearing and Speed Accuracy

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to use [Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) for one time location update, I am not sure effect of these two functions?

1. setSpeedAccuracy()
2. setBearingAccuracy()

setBearingRequired() and setSpeedRequired() says about do we need these information when fix is available, not about accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

`setBearingRequired()` and `setSpeedRequired()` tells a `LocationProvider` that you want that information, if available.

`setBearingAccuracy()` and `setSpeedRequired()` tells a `LocationProvider` how accurate you want the answer to be when it gives you that information.

Bearing is the direction the device is pointing at/moving in. Speed is how fast the device is moving.

Comment: Thanks @phxhawke I get it, but what does that Bearing/Speed accuracy means? is it speed of device movement? or speed in term of time it took to deliver GPS fix? e.g. setHorizontalAccuracy means latitude/longitude accuracy.